# What's the difference between getMobileTx/RxBytes() and getTotalTx/RxBytes() in TrafficStats?

Tags: java, android

The first two methods talk about a "mobile interface" and the other two about "all network interfaces." What do those mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would *expect* "all network interfaces" to include WiFi (and wired if the device happens to support that), but "mobile interface" only to include data via a cell connection (3G, GPRS etc).

Comment: This is right, however it is not obvious from the documentation or source (since it's all done natively instead of through Java).

Comment: ^Exactly the reason why I asked. This is my theory too, I just wasn't sure enough.